# Sphinx и Sphinxql

Tags: php, sphinx, mysql

Установил сфинкс, проиндексировал, настройки такие:

```
    source          = objectsSource
    path            = /home/*****/sphinx/
    docinfo         = extern
    mlock           = 0
    morphology      = stem_en, stem_ru, stem_enru, soundex, metaphone
    blend_chars = -,+,U+20
    enable_star=1

    html_strip  = 1
```

Нужно найти сочетание "z-plaza".
В строке пишу: `search zplaza`
Находит.

Подключаюсь mysql клиентом и пишу `select * from objectsIndex where match('zplaza');`

Не находит! Уже и не знаю, что нужно настроить, помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Вы показали запрос "один к одному"? Как бы синтаксис такой:

    SELECT * 
      FROM `comments` 
    WHERE MATCH(`field_name`) AGAINST('zplaza');
    // в логическом режиме, например так
    SELECT * 
      FROM `comments` 
    WHERE MATCH(`field_name`) AGAINST('+zplaza' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

Comment: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/archives/1.10/sphinxql-select.html

Такого как у вас нигде нет, попробовал, ругается на синтаксис)

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего ваша проблема связана с несоответствием кодировок, искомого и индексируемого. В последниех версиях Sphinx (например 2.2.9), он работает только с utf8.

Советую вам попробовать запустить mysql клиент с явным указанием кодировки:

```
c:\mysql\bin\mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 9306 --default-character-set=cp1251
c:\mysql\bin\mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 9306 --default-character-set=utf8
```

У себя я так и не смог настроить mysql доступ, но через PHP API все работает идеально, для перекодировок пользуюсь:

```
iconv("UTF-8", "CP1251", $string);
iconv("CP1251", "UTF-8", $string);
```

соответственно, удачи.